# Break a list-item to a new line when it exceeds width of container

Tags: html, css

I have a div `position:absolute` inside a `relative` container div. The `absolute` positioned `div` has a percentage width, and when I reduce the browser size, thus shrinking the `div`'s size the `li` text get's cut off, I will include a screenshot. I want the text in the `li` to break to a new line without writing a `<br>` because these will be generated dynamically. Ok here is my code

//HTML

```
<div class="information-toggle">
    <aside class="information-toggle__list">
        <ul>
            <li>Meaningless Existence</li>
            <li>Meaningless Existence</li>
            <li>Meaningless Existence</li>
            <li>Meaningless Existence</li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <div class="information-toggle__content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
</div>
```

//SASS

```
.information-toggle{
    // border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-family: 'Avenir',sans-serif;
}
.information-toggle__list{
    width:100%;
    // border:1px dashed green;
    z-index: 100;
    position:relative;   
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        position:absolute;
        width:25%;
    }
    ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        overflow-x:scroll;
        white-space: nowrap;
        @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
            display:list-item;
            overflow-x:initial;
        }
        li{
            background: $button-red;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
            font-weight: 500;
            @include font-size(2.0);
            letter-spacing: 0.08px;
            position: relative;
            height: 46px;
            line-height: 46px;
            display: inline-block;
            color: $white;
            margin: 5px;
            border-radius:5px;
            @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
                display:list-item;
                border-radius:initial;
                border-top-left-radius:5px;
                border-bottom-left-radius:5px;  
                margin:initial;
                height: 67px;
                line-height: 67px;
            }
            &:hover {
                background:$button-red-hover;
                @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
                    @include rightArrow();
                    font-weight:900;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
.information-toggle__content{
    width: 100%;
    // border: 1px dashed orange;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 25px;
    background: $white;
    //transform: translateY(33px);
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        padding: 50px;
        width: 75%;
        transform: translateY(33px);
    }
}
```

and here is what it looks like to me
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the parent div, use;

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/z3y20ckv/)

Comment: any idea how to bring a list item of an unordered list to the next line if it exceeds parent div.?

Answer (score 0):

On `li` item put `whitespace: normal`, `height: auto` and `min-height: 67px`

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `overflow-wrap: break-word;` on parent div.